# Brew in a bag partial boil

Tags: brewing, biab, partial-boil

I was flipping through BrewDog's recently [released catalog](https://www.brewdog.com/diydog) of their recipes and there are a couple I'd like to have a go at.

I was originally going to ask how to convert some of the recipes to extract but then did some reading about the [brew-in-a-bag](http://homebrewmanual.com/brew-in-a-bag/) method.

So some quick questions with an example in mind:

[image]

In this recipe, the grain bill calls for Extra Pale - Maris Otter, Caramalt and Munich.

**1) For the BIAB method - Do I simply add all the grain to a bag, insert into my kettle and hold at 65c / 69c for an hour?**

**2) Is it possible to use less water in the boil rather than the full volume? e.g Have ~17.5L boil and top up with cold water at the end?**

Comment: Do you have conditions to perform a lager fermentation?

Comment: Yeah I think so, we recently built a keezer with its own temp control so keeping it around 10c should be a breeze.

Comment: Note that they call for 16C, when yeast manufacturer calls for 9-13C. Your call. Personally I'd go with wyeast and 10C if i could... but probably my clone wouldn't be perfect.

Comment: I think that 16c is a mistake, in the bottom right under "Brewer's Tip" it mentions that it should be close to 12C or below.

Comment: you're right. Well, they got some errors in editing. As long as you know or at least think what you're doing, it'll be OK.

Comment: Keep in mind when thinking about temps they probably copied their temp into this recipe.  Going from a much larger fermentor to 5 gallons would require a lower temp than they report.  As Molot said 10C is probably a better choice.  The larger format fermentor creates more hydrostatic pressure on the yeast which suppresses ester formation.  A warmer ferment (16C) would produce less esters than a ferment of 5 gallons at 16C as a result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you do simply put all grain (crushed!) in a bag. That's the point.

**However** Brewdog's catalog calls for fly sparging, something you simply won't do. With fly sparging, your extraction efficiency can be about 80%. Yesterday I hit 95% *(again, against my plan, and I really hate it, but that's just btw)*. Even 90% should be perfectly doable. Without sparge, best reported results I have seen was at 70%. Usually worse. This means you need [20-25 percent more grain than a standard recipe](http://byo.com/malt/item/1375-skip-the-sparge). If you will just use bag without adjusting grain bill, your beer would turn out weak, watery, and tasteless compared to original. For first try, **keep some DME at hand**, to correct your wort if needed. Once you know your efficiency, you can calculate exact amount of grain to hit OG you need.

Using less water for boil is possible, but **don't do it** if you can avoid it. Full volume boil will allow you to extract hops just the way they did it. And that's the way if you want to brew a perfect clone. Less water can cause worse extraction of alpha acids. Also, it can promote maillard reactions - something you might want sometimes, but definitely does not look like planned in this recipe. Oh, and if you have to do a partial boil, top it with **well boiled** water, not just cold tap one.

Comment: Good call with the DME, I might pick up a couple of KG to whip up a starter as well.

I really wanted to do a partial boil as the copper chiller I have is useless / takes hours to cool. I've taken to putting 3/4 Kg of Ice into partial boil's to top up to my desired batch size. Its very effective at reducing the temp. to ~20c almost instantly..

Comment: @Tomcelic whatever is sterile. But keep hop utilization and maillard reactions in mind. For not-so-hoppy, not-so-strong beer it shouldn't be a problem. I hope. Still, would try to avoid that.

Comment: Note that you can double-crush your grains to improve your efficiency with BIAB. I do a fairly fine crush (my mill is set to 0.035") on my grains and I usually get between 75 and 80% efficiency. Since you don't have to worry about a stuck sparge you can grind pretty fine. Definitely try to do a full-volume mash, though.

Comment: Howdy - quick update / question: I followed the steps to do a full volume / all grain batch. Everything went smoothly (used 25% more grain etc.) but went I took the O.G is was 20 points over (~0.0.65), eek! I diluted with water to get about 25L @ 0.045 instead of 20L @ 0.065. Is this likely to the mash being more efficient than expected, using too much grain or the mash being too hot?

Bonus question - I need to brew 40L of ale in the next few days but only have enough room to mash / boil about 25L of liquid.. any ideas how to best handle this situation?

Comment: @Tomcelic Ask this as a new question, please. Actually, two. Also, try to calculate your efficiency.